# Lazarus IDE - Compile fails: Cannot open include file

Tags: compiler-errors, lazarus

I wanted to try my luck with Lazarus IDE, when encountered several problems that keep me from running my first ever program. I solved several of them, with doubtful solutions I made up from thin air, but I'm stuck on this particular problem, and couldn't find assistance in Google (^-^).

I use Lazarus version 1.0.8 with FPC version 2.6.2. My OS is Windows 8.1 x64.

The error I encounter now is:

```
C:\Lazarus\App\lazarus\packager\registration\jwawinnt.pas(59,2) Fatal: Can't open include file "jediapilib.inc".
```

That file I found it and its location is `C:\Lazarus\App\lazarus\fpc\2.6.2\source\packages\winunits-jedi\src`

This error jumps from the unit `JwaWinNT.pas`. The include is at line 59: `{$I jediapilib.inc}`

Well, hope I'm not annoying too much anybody. See ya later.

LeoAM

Comment: Try to install [the latest stable version of Lazarus & FPC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Windows%2032%20bits/Lazarus%201.2.6/)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you use a package that packages unit "jwawinnt" which also comes with FPC, and then all hell breaks loose.

Try to remove the jwa* stuff from the package and see if it will work with the Jedi windows headers provided with FPC.

Comment: Yes, I got the jwa Jedi provided by fpc. The problem it seems that lazarus creates its own `jwawinnt.pas` in the same folder as `ServiceManager.pas` after I delete it. Otherwise, all "jwa" files appear in the fpc folder.